# Error with divmod

Tags: python, divmod

Trying to run some code.  Get this error when I do.  I thought I had all the necessary dependencies installed, but still getting this error.

linux; GNU C++ version 4.8.1; Boost_105300; UHD_003.007.000-133-g6bd9fed2

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/tpms_rx", line 274, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/bin/tpms_rx", line 265, in main
    tb = top_block(source, args)
  File "/usr/local/bin/tpms_rx", line 229, in __init__
    self.source = source_rtlsdr(args.tuned_frequency, args.if_rate)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tpms/source.py", line 98, in __init__
    rf_decimation, rf_decimation_remainder = divmod(rf_sampling_rate, if_sampling_rate)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for divmod(): 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Also, why are you talking about your C++ compiler version when you appear to be using Python?

Comment: Looks like either of your 2 parameters passed into **divmod** is `None`

Answer (score 0):

When you run your program you need to pass a parameter `-i`/`--if-rate` or else the default is `None` which eventually gets passed, 2 layers later, to `divmod`.

See https://github.com/jboone/gr-tpms/blob/master/apps/tpms_rx and https://github.com/jboone/gr-tpms/blob/master/python/source.py additionally.

Comment: So what parameter is it looking for?  I see the frequency is already set, is it looking for something else that I need to determine?  Have you got this to work, and if so what did you use?